# Confusion: Ajax Framework vs JavaScript Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was under the impression that jQuery is JavaScript Framework, but when am searching for AJAX Framework it appears that jQuery is also being suggested as best AJAX Framework.

Reference: [Best Ajax Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321/best-ajax-framework)

My Question:

1. What is Ajax Framework and how it is different from JavaScript Framework like jQuery ?
2. What are best known Ajax Framework ?
3. What are best known JavaScript Framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is a way to asynchronously communicate with a server using Javascript. jQuery provides functions to help you do AJAX things, so it's an AJAX framework, but it also provides other Javascript tools, so it's a general Javascript framework too.

"Best" rather depends on what you want the framework to do; I happen to like jQuery for both

Answer (score 1):

Understand the terms and the relationships:

- AJAX (Async. **JavaScript** and XML) uses JavaScript
- JavaScript is a scripting language
- Therefore, AJAX is a feature of Web JavaScript
- jQuery is a JavaScript framework
- Therefore, jQuery can include AJAX features

About the best AJAX and JS frameworks... I tried jQuery and I was satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) is just what it sounds like: a javascript technique for asynchronous communication (that is, you don't have to reload the page).

Of course, you can use javascript without ajax, but "ajax without javascript" is meaningless.

My personal favorite framework for both is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, one of my biggest pet peeves is when people are like "oh, yeah, there's no Flash on this site, it's **all AJAX**" in reference to the animation used. AJAX was *initially* coined to refer to the technique of using javascript to asynchronously load XML (or sometimes json) data from a server via an `XMLHttpRequest`. Many Javascript frameworks (jQuery, prototype, mootools) have implementations of AJAX methodologies wrapped in them, but to call these frameworks an "AJAX framework" is misleading as they do much more. But AJAX has become a defacto buzzword over the years so:

1) there's really no difference
2+3) jQuery, prototype, mootools are the big three. jQuery is the most popular (and in my humble opinion, easily the best)

Answer (score 0):

1.
- Ajax framework to develop web applications which is using Ajax, a collection of technologies used to build dynamic web pages on the client side
- main obj is to provide the Ajax engine and associated server and client-side function
- Ajax use Javascript by name Ajax means Asynchronous Javascript and XML. While doing client side Validation you can use javascript and suppose you want to call any Server side Method you can use Ajax.
- Ajax can be use when want postback to happen eg. On selection category load subcategory.

2.
- Direct Ajax frameworks, Indirect Ajax frameworks, Ajax component frameworks, Server-driven Ajax frameworks

3.
JavaScript framework jquery, prototype.js, mootools, Dojo and YUI.